# Advice about modeling visit data retrospectively

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, count-data, medicine

I have retrospective patient level data on number of emergency department visits in a given year for a large urban ED -  mostly 1's and 2's but range up to over 20 (data were collected at an ED visit so no zeroes). 40% have 1 visit, 55% have <=2. I also have a set of predictors of this outcome - a mix of demographics and 'substantive' predictors. They are a mix of continuous, semi continuous, and categorical variables. My struggle is to determine the correct model for the outcome.

- A transformation of the outcome to normalize it was somewhat successful (e.g., to perform multiple regression or ANOVA),  but I have the feeling that the underlying phenomenon is not in fact a continuous phenomenon.
- Logistic regression is a possibility, but the categorization of the outcome as binary would be arbitrary. I'm not sure where to set the cut point, etc.
- I've thought about cluster analysis but it loses the ability to really directly interpret the significance of the predictors.
- Multinomial logistic regression is just hard to interpret

Thoughts or references?

Comment: These are count data. A count model (e.g., Poisson GLM) is appropriate. If the time under observation differs by patient, you may want to use an offset.

Comment: We have a similar prediction problem in the ecommerce space. Customers coming back to place orders. As an exploratory exercise what really helped was building conditional models. Given that a patient has visited once can you predict who will return. From then build those who have visited twice who will return etc.

Comment: Rohit, thanks.. Can you point me toward something more specific about these models? GLM models? etc How did you model the outcome? This does sound like something I would like to look into.